# Adding gaussian noise in fortran to an array of data

Tags: fortran

I need some help in adding Gaussian noise to my Fortran code. I have to basically construct an array of size 4. I enter the value into the array and then I have to add the noise. I have tried looking this up on the internet and have found solutions which uses an array of random numbers and then adds guassian noise to the array, but was unable to find solution for adding the noise to a pre-set array.

I have given the part of the code below

```
real, dimesnsion(1:4):: stoke

!create an array
stoke(1)=sum_iu
stoke(2)=diff_iu
stoke(3)=sum_iq
stoke(4)=diff_iq

do ij=1,4

   print*, 'stoke=' ,ij,'=',stoke(ij)

end do

! add gaussian noise to the data

do ij=1,xx-1,2

      temp= sd*sqrt(-2.0*log(stoke(ij)))*cos(2*pi*(stoke(ij+1)))+mean
      stoke(ij+1)=sd*sqrt(-2.0*log(stoke(ij))) * sin(2*pi*(stoke(ij+1)))+mean
      stoke(ij)=temp

print*,'the values are= ','stoke(ij)',stoke(ij),'stoke(ij+1)',stoke(ij+1)
end do
```

When I run this it outputs the result as NaN for the four output values. But in case I use a random number `array(size=4)` in place of `stokes(4)` it does display the numbers.

Comment: So, what is `xx` and what is `diff_iq`?

Comment: Don't use the snippet feature, it is for javascript only.

Comment: The source of NaNs are quite likely linked to the value of stoke(ij), which, if it is greater than one, will make the argument of the sqrt negative, and so the nan. Print the value of stoke at the entrance of the loop and you will see.

Comment: Thanks Edmondo Giovannozzi. The value of soke is greater than one so i guess thats the value.

Comment: Are you trying to add newly generated (independent) Gaussian random numbers (with mean "mean" and standard deviation "sd" to the array "stroke(1:4)"? Then I guess the arguments of log etc should be uniform random numbers always.

Comment: this is really unclear what you are asking, and not really a fortran question so much as an algorithm question.  (Looks like you started plugging away coding without knowing what the algorithm is supposed to be)

Comment: roygvib . yes i was trying to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are probably using the [Box-Muller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) method for generating two Gaussian random numbers from two uniform random numbers. So, if Gaussian noises are to be added to existing arrays (here `stoke`), I guess the code will become like this:

```
do ij = 1, size( stoke )-1, 2   !! assuming the array size is even...

    u = rand()   !! uniform random number in [0,1)
    v = rand()   !! same as above (another sample)

    stoke( ij   ) = stoke( ij   ) + sd * sqrt(-2.0*log( u )) * cos( 2*pi * v ) + mean
    stoke( ij+1 ) = stoke( ij+1 ) + sd * sqrt(-2.0*log( u )) * sin( 2*pi * v ) + mean
end do
```

Comment: To prevent very rare cases of u=0, it may be better to attach a code to reject it and re-sample u.